# How to add SameSite:none in cookies via Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, csrf

I am trying to add the samesite:none in all our cookies through web.config. I have tried the following using the rewrite rules but to no avail:

```
  <outboundRules>
  <rule name="Add SameSite None">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="true" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=none" />
  </outboundRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=none" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="No SameSite">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=none" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```